# Can I become a Muslim Comic artist

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

I love drawing comics, they are my lively hood and I hope I can be one amidst all the logical careers I have to choose from. I know that drawing a person isn't good, but is okay if they are not realistic. The people would still include their eyes and noes and mouths, but I wouldn't give them tear ducts, or nostrils (depending on the panel) and I wouldn't show divisions in their teeth when I drew them (and its impossible to have one big tooth spanning your whole mouth so that's unrealistic right?). Also I draw "manga" which is the Japanese style of drawing comics where girls usually have unrealistically large eyes, and Guys have unrealistically long faces (and eyelashes are very undetailed). What I'm trying to say is, is it okay for me to draw comics if the people are unrealistic but not absurdly unrealistic? Thank you so much for taking your time to answer this!

Answer (score 2):

It is not permissible, if it is living beings then it is not permissible even if it wasn't realistic. According to this hadith

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The most severely punished of the people on the Day of Resurrection will be the image-makers.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari (5950) and Muslim (2109).

the Prophet said: “Those who depict images will be punished on the Day of Resurrection; it will be said to them: 'Breathe a soul into what you have depicted.’” [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]

However, if the picture is not complete; i.e., it is missing a part that is essential for life, such as the head or the chest, then, according to many scholars, such a picture is permissible.

In your drawing which includes the head and the mouth is not permissible, it should not include the whole head or a part of the body that will leave it lifeless. As long as the character looks lifeless it is permissible.

Answer (score -2):

As your question seems more about realistic/unrealist than about the drawing of living beings rights.
I think realistic and unrealistic is the same. I can't see anywhere in hadeeths where there's a difference between both.

Simple logical rule:

If you consider halal drawing persons, unrealistic is allowed. 
If you consider haram drawing persons, urealistic is forbidden.